# Write a method strange_words that accepts an array of strings

Tags: javascript

Write a method strange_words that accepts an array of strings. The method should return an array containing all strings that are either shorter than 6 characters or begin with "e", but are not both shorter than 6 character and also begin with "e".

The last part of the question just confuses me. This is what I have so far:

```
function strangeWords(words) {
  for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      if (words.length < 6 && words[0] !== "e" || words[0] === "e" && words.length > 6) {
      
    }
    return words;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume "words" is an array of strings.

You need to create an empty array, fill it up with words that matches your condition, then return the array. An example will be as follows.

```
function strangeWords(words) {

  let filteredWords = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      if (words[i].length < 6 && words[i][0] !== "e" || words[i][0] === "e" && words[i].length > 6) {
      filteredWords.push(words[i])
    }
   
  }
  return filteredWords;
}
```

A better way is to use the filter function, which returns only strings that matches your condition. Example as follows.

```
function strangeWords(words) {

  return words.filter(word => {
     //Your conditions here.
     return (word.length < 6 && word[0] !== "e" || word[0] === "e" && word.length > 6) 
  }
}
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: I think `filter` should return a `boolean` and not return the value? Well, I think `word` is `truthy` because it will have a value if it passes the filter. I think it would be better if you can just `return (word.length < 6 && word[0] !== "e" || word[0] === "e" && word.length > 6)`?

Comment: filter returns boolean

Answer (score 0):

The question is essentially asking you to filter the provided input array based on the conditions given to you.

What you need to do now is to create a new array, and push the values that satisfy those conditions inside your if block.

```
output.push(words[i]);
return output;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is all you will need I negated the condition for all strings that starts with e and length is less than 6

So basically what is happening is filter checks if string is length <6 and starts with "e" and if it does it does not include it in result

```js
let test = ["abc", "ertyujkhgf", "trfvdfgrwgs", "ertfs"];

out = test.filter(ele=>{return ele[0]==="e" ^ ele.length<6})

console.log(out)
```

[image]

This image is a simple Venn Diagram showing overlap of words starting with e and length < 6

So Mathematically We Want

Set A Set of all words starting with e
Set B Set of all words with length less than 6

Every thing from set A and Set B That is not in A∩B

Which will look like
[image]

Everything in white area And this is equal to a XOR operation On A and B

> `A ^ B`

Comment: And you miss a condition... The word "trfvdfgrwgs" should not be in the results.

Answer (score 0):

I would make it this way, more readable when you have names for your conditions.

You also did not use your loop index, so I added it.

```
function strangeWords(words)
{
    let result = [];
    let isShorterThanSix;
    let isBeginWithE;

    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        isShorterThanSix = words[i].length < 6;
        isBeginWithE = words[i][0] === 'e';

        if(isShorterThanSix || isBeginWithE){
            if(isShorterThanSix && isBeginWithE){
                continue;
            }
            //Add only the needed items to the result
            result.push(words[i]);
        }

      return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your variable name is `isBeginWithE` but the value is `not equal` to `e`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex filter words that are:

1. Start with `e` and has a length greater than 6
2. Does not start with `e` and length less than or equal to 6

```
const regex = /^(e.{6,}|[^e].{0,5})$/;

function strangeWords(words) {
   return words.filter(word => regex.test(word));
}
```

```js
const regex = /^(e.{6,}|[^e].{0,5})$/;

function strangeWords(words) {
   return words.filter(word => regex.test(word));
}

console.log(
  strangeWords([
    "e123456",  // VALID: Starts with `e` and has length 7
    "123456",   // VALID: Does not start 'e' and has length 6
    "123",      // VALID: length less then 6
    "e123",     // INVALID: start with `e` but length less then 6
    "1234556d"  // INVALID: length greater then 6
  ])
)
```